How in meilisearch set TIMEZONE parameter for datas uploaded from laravel scout?
Regenerating demo data on laravel 11 site with command :
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

and checking data in meilisearch v1.11.3 for searchable table I see that created_at field is 2 hours less in mysql database.
In .env file I have :
APP_TIMEZONE='Europe/Kiev'

But I did not found any similar parameter in config/scout.php.
I searched in https://www.meilisearch.com/docs and did not find any reference.
Can I set TIMEZONE parameter for meilisearch ?
    "laravel/framework": "^11.27.2",
    "laravel/scout": "^10.11",

Thanks in advance!
